# Googlemap loading issue in div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load googlemap inside div. My script is as follows

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?

    key=AIzaSyAiy_9XkvL8a5-zsSV5jFpH8sHcth5HkpE&callback=myMap"></script>

    <script>
    function myMap() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.015509, 72.843067),
                    zoom: 10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            }
    </script>
```

And on the loading of page I am getting error. I have attached an image of error.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly where you're wrong.
But by the error you get.
The function is not set correctly.
Or that it is not within the local scope.
But you should view a map of Google.
If an address you want.
There's another way to get this into your code.
Just enter Google Maps and select correspondence and just paste it into the code.
I attach an example that you can understand.
What I mean exactly.

```
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2702.5938589941825!2d8.640130883976095!3d47.36132677916924!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x479aa3ffb7057dbb%3A0x8dfd514b03a2c801!2sBodenacherstrasse+52%2C+8121+F%C3%A4llanden!5e0!3m2!1siw!2sch!4v1505149050010" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move you script myMap() before the googleapis call

```
<script>
    function myMap() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.015509, 72.843067),
                    zoom: 10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?

    key=AIzaSyAiy_9XkvL8a5-zsSV5jFpH8sHcth5HkpE&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your scripts in the wrong order.  You are loading the Google Maps Javascript API v3 without the `defer async` tags, so when it finishes loading (inline), it will attempt to call the function `myMap`, which is defined (inline) after the script include.  Reverse the order.

proof of concept:

- [fiddle with original order](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/oqt33fkj/)

error: `Uncaught Vb {message: "myMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Vb (https://maps.googleapis.com/m….googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap:144:59"}`

- [fiddle with reordered code](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/oqt33fkj/1/)

(no errors, loads map)

**working code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function myMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.015509, 72.843067),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google uses initMap as default function so use `initMap()` instead of `myMap()`

Try this:

```
function initMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.015509, 72.843067),
            scrollwheel: false
        };
```